# GCP Create or replace Cloud Run Job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Is there a GCP command for creating OR replacing a cloud run job?  I'm using github-actions to create cloud run and scheduler jobs, and need to keep switching the commands between:

```
gcloud alpha run jobs create
```

and

```
gcloud alpha run jobs update
```

Is there a way to create the job and overwrite it if it already exists?

Comment: For info, the team is working on a more user friendly usage, something like gcloud run deploy, but for cloud run jobs, where you don't have to check if a previous deployment exist or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcloud beta run jobs deploy` was recently added to gcloud which does what you're looking for. Documentation is [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/jobs/deploy)

Comment: This is great, I hope it gets rolled out to cloud scheduler jobs too.

Answer (score 1):

To create a [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs#command-line) new job :

```bash
gcloud beta run jobs create JOB_NAME --image IMAGE_URL OPTIONS
```

To update existing job :

```bash
gcloud beta run jobs update JOB_NAME
```

If you want a single command to handle the creation and update at the same time, you can develop your own `Shell` script, example :

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
set -o pipefail
set -u

export JOB_NAME=my_job

res=$(gcloud beta run jobs describe $JOB_NAME --region=europe-west1 || echo "NOT_EXIST")

echo "#######Result : $res"

if [ "$res" = "NOT_EXIST" ]; then
  echo "Creating your job..."
  gcloud beta run jobs create $JOB_NAME
else
  echo "Updating your job..."
  gcloud beta run jobs update $JOB_NAME
fi
```

Comment: Is it possible to integrate this into a github workflow? I guess you would just have to run it all as one step in the workflow. I will give it a go. Would be nice if there were just a flag i.e. `gcloud beta run jobs create --force`

Comment: Yes it's possible. You are right, it would be nice but I think there is no such of parameter in `gcloud` command.